# while creating indexed View , Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to create a indexed view . i need to set dateformat and create the view . code is as follows:

```
Create view vWMaterializedView 
with schemaBInding
as
set dateformat dmy  
select 
Case 
  when CAST([Payment Date] AS datetime) BETWEEN CAST('16/07/2017' as datetime) AND CAST('15/07/2018' AS date) then '2074/75'   
  end as Fiscal_Year ,
  from dbo.[Final Payment Bill] FBP
```

Comment: `end as Fiscal_Year ,` <-- stray comma here, but what kind of fiscal year is `2074/75`?  Also, much of your handling of dates is unnecessary and could be improved.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact it's an *indexed* view - you just cannot have a `SET DATEFORMAT` statement inside a view definition - only a `SELECT` ..... [see the official Microsoft docs on `CREATE VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) for details of the valid syntax

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just a local date time fiscal year in my country ..

Comment: @marc_s what could be the possible solution ?? i need to set the format and also create the view

Comment: You just simply **cannot** set the format inside the view definition - this has to be done **externally** to the view definition

Comment: @SudipBala, do you need to set the `DATAFORMAT` because `Payment_Date]` is `varchar`? The solution is to change the column type to `datetime` or `datetime2` and use ISO 8601 format datetime literals so that the view can be indexed.